# tv series production

Tags: television, equipment

What are the microphones, cameras and mixers used in recording a television series?

Comment: 1. Google Earth most certainly doesn't have anything to do with your question. 2. Please try and start your sentences with a capital letter and use a space after a comma.
What brought you to pose this question? Is there a specific background to it? Are you planning on renting a whole setup for yourself?... Although there are knowledgeable people here who may know about cameras, I reckon it should be discussed somewhere else, on a camera enthusiasts board.

Comment: Are you a produce looking to budget something or a sound guy looking to figure something out?  More detail...


Comment: This is really more of a question for Audio/Video Production and [this question](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/what-equipment-should-i-get-for-starting-out-making-professional-quality-films) may already provide your answer.

Answer (score 3):

At Footnote, we're using the Sony EX3 for our host shoots, we're using a Letus to give it a little more character and make it feel less like video. Out on the road we use mainly Cannon 7D and 5D.

As for audio, our field recorder is a Sound Devices 788T (love that thing) For host shoots we use a Neumann TLM 103 (Love that mic!) On the road our main mic for interviews is a Lectrosonics MM400c with a Countryman B6. MM400c is great because it's "water proof" I say that because everything has it's limits, but it's a good pack. And you won't find a better lav then countryman. (well maybe, but then you're really dropping some coin.)

I have had over all good results with this setup.

Peter-John Campbell

Answer (score 2):

Lots of different ones.

Answer (score 1):

That question is too broad to be answered, you need to be more specific. Are you just generally interested, or are you planning on getting involved with the audio side of a T.V. series? Try searching the forum before posting, most likely the results will enable you to fine-tune your request into something we can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SSD.

Please be a little more specific on what exactly you'd like to find out about TV production.

This is certainly a board you can ask questions about TV audio, but it's mostly a Sound Design oriented group of individuals who discuss Sound Design concepts. To ask a question so general I consider a waste of a valuable resource that has become known as SSD. Every single person who frequents this board is professional in some aspect of the Sound Design industry, so their time and advice is golden. This seems more like a question for Yahoo Answers and has most likely already been answered elsewhere.

I like to think of it as kind of like the major leagues of Sound Design for the TV, Film, Performing Arts and Gaming industry.

I'm sure this link will get you what you're asking for:

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=what+mics+are+used+for+television+shows?

Comment: But don't try this. http://tinyurl.com/3rk8yvw Houston, we have a problem. Crrrsh.